Elpaca Configuration Not Cooperating
new user to GNU Emacs (installed Emacs 3 days ago). I had fun learning and configuring my Emacs experience using use-package so far. Everything was working smoothly.
I decided to switch to Elpaca as my package manager because it seemed more featureful and I liked the idea of syncing and updating packages asynchronously. However, since I migrated to Elpaca, I've have a bunch of errors.
For example, I  used to have Hydra installed, and it would always output: Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function defhydra) whenever I had a defhydra call in my config... I removed Hydra, thinking that it would fix the issue only to face this when I restarted Emacs...
⛔ Error (use-package): Cannot load general
⛔ Error (use-package): Cannot load evil
⛔ Error (use-package): ivy-rich/:init: Symbol’s function definition is void: ivy-rich-mode
⛔ Error (use-package): Cannot load ivy-rich
⛔ Error (use-package): Cannot load counsel-projectile
⛔ Error (use-package): Cannot load magit
⛔ Error (use-package): Cannot load lsp-ivy
⛔ Error (use-package): Cannot load all-the-icons
⛔ Error (use-package): doom-modeline/:init: Symbol’s function definition is void: doom-modeline-mode
⛔ Error (use-package): Cannot load doom-modeline
⛔ Error (use-package): doom-themes/:init: Unable to find theme file for ‘doom-gruvbox’
⛔ Error (use-package): Cannot load doom-themes
⛔ Error (use-package): org/:config: Symbol’s value as variable is void: mind-fonts-family

No idea what the issue is. I did go through the Elpaca manual and the Elpaca migration documentation but couldn't fix it myself. I come from Neovim, so I know what it's like to struggle with configuration.
You can view the config file here.
Thank you very much guys!

EDIT
I found the problem.
I forgot the :ensure t on all the packages.
For future reference or anyone having similar issues, as an alternative to adding :ensure t to all packages call, you can add this line to your config if you enable use-package with Elpaca:
      (setq use-package-always-ensure t)

This will make sure all the packages you load with use-package are properly installed before loading (well I think that's what it does lol).
